# issue in json with date

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to fetch transaction from the db for the current date using JSON.stringify. But it is taking the previous date in the java bean object.

I select the start date and end date to the current date(20th Mar 2014). and Below is the code in jsp json.

```
var json = {
    "reportTypeId" : reportTypeId,
    "fromDate" : $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', fromDate),
    "toDate" : $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd',toDate),
    "jurisdictionId" : jurisdictionId 
};
alert(JSON.stringify(json));

$.ajax({
        url : "adminviewreports/displayReports",
        type : "POST",
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        data : JSON.stringify(json),
        success : function(data) { 
            $("#spinner").hide();
            if (reportTypeId == 2) {    
                loadAuditTable(data);
                $('#activity').show();
                $("#auditReportDiv").show();
            }
            if (reportTypeId == 3) {
                loadSecurityTable(data); 
                $('#security').show();
                $("#securityReportDiv").show();
            }
        },
        error : function() {
           $("#spinner").hide();
           alert("Error Occurred while getting audit events");
        }
});
```

and in the java bean object is the date is

```
private Date fromDate;
private Date toDate;
public Date getFromDate() {
    LOGGER.error("in bean fromDate============"+fromDate);
    return fromDate;
}
/**
 * @param fromDate the fromDate to set
 */
public void setFromDate(Date fromDate) {
    this.fromDate = fromDate;
}
/**
 * @return the toDate
 */
public Date getToDate() {
    LOGGER.error("in bean toDate============"+fromDate);
    return toDate;
}
/**
 * @param toDate the toDate to set
 */
public void setToDate(Date toDate) {
    this.toDate = toDate;
}
```

if I put the alert in json i am getting current date as 2014-03-20 but while setting this date to the javabean object it is taking as Wed Mar 19 20:00:00 EDT 2014. If I deploy the code in local mechine(in India) I a getting the correct date. But If I deploy the code in the mechine which is located in USA I am getting this issue. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: As below answers indicate, the issue is that a client's date is taken as the absolute time. The issue can be addressed by using an ISO timestamp or using the UTC milliseconds approach to saving date.

Can you share more on what you will be using the date values for?

Comment: @aravind   I checked the date in DB and for 20th and there are few records in the db for the current date. But since the java object date is taking as previous date so it is not displaying the data.

Comment: Ok, then try checking when it is received from the client. If it is still the current date before saving in DB and in DB too, then your problem lies in reading the date from your DB. Not the JSON, since JSON is just sending a string to the server "14-03-20"

Comment: it is saving current date for any event. But the problem is while passing the current date as input parameter through json call, it is taking previous date in the java bean object which json converts.

Answer (score 0):

```
India is 9:30 hours ahead of USA
```

Javascript/jquery will read the time from client machine. 
Since you are using browser in India, so getting 20-03-2014.

And server machine is deployed in USA. For that server system current date is **Wed Mar 19 20:00:00 EDT 2014**, so javabean object is using that time.

That's the reason you are getting different dates

Comment: I checked the date in USA box, it is showing :

**Thu Mar 20 03:23:18 EDT 2014**

Answer (score 0):

Ok to fix your problem you have to send and use time zone.

Server-side, add a new field in your json named timezone set it to the correct time zone of the date in milliseconds and send it to the client.

User-side, add this

```
var jetLag = 0;
var serverTimeZone = json.timeZone;
var userTimeZone = new Date().getTimeZone() * 60 * 1000;

if( serverTimeZone > userTimeZone ){

    jetLag =  Math.abs(serverTimeZone - userTimeZone);

else {

    jetLag = -Math.abs(serverTimeZone - userTimeZone);

};

var dateWithOffset = new Date(oldDate.getTime() + jetLag);
```